# Downsides to whitelisting localhost in mod_security?

Tags: apache, whm, mod-security, mod-security2

I've just enabled mod_security on my CentOS server via WHM with OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set.

I've seen some very useful stuff so far but also some very annoying, not very useful things such as:

```
016-06-23 10:00:01      127.0.0.1   WARNING 200  960008: Request Missing a Host Header

2016-06-23 10:00:01     127.0.0.1   NOTICE  200  960009: Request Missing a User Agent Header  More

2016-06-23 10:00:01     127.0.0.1       200  981204: Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Inbound Score: 5): Request Missing a User Agent Header
```

Basically 95% of the hits (which are a lot) are like this, form localhost.

What is this exactly? And are there security concerns should I simply whitelist localhost?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Only you can answer this to be honest.

It sounds like you have something running locally which connects to you webserver. Maybe a script to check if the site is up? Maybe something else that gets something webserver.

Whatever it is not setting:

1. The Host Header: which site you want to visit - so guessing script is using IP address to connect or just not passing the hostname.
2. The user agent: all browsers pass a user agent so when this is not present its highly likely it's a script. That's not to say whether that script is malicious or useful.

Neither of those rules are really problems or security concerns in themselves. They are just a sign that it's likely not a browser so likely is a script so maybe want to block.

To be honest I'd find out what is doing this. As I say I would guess it might be a heartbeat check script to check site it still up. If so, then no problem whitelisting localhost for these two rules. If not then you can decide whether you want to whitelist or not.

I personally prefer to only whitelist what's necessary rather than blanket whitelist all of localhost, so to whitelist these rules you can add config like this BEFORE the rules (as the ctl command expects the rules it's amending to come after it):

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 127.0.0.1" "id:1000,phase:2,nolog,ctl:ruleRemoveById=960008;ctl:ruleRemoveById=960009"
```

Comment: It happens also on a new server with a website that has nothing on it.

Comment: You must still have a script installed which checks if it's up.